# Why is my default alert dialog button text white?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, material-components-android, android-ktx

I have set up my app as follows:

**build.gradle**

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`

**styles.xml**

```
    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

**CheckoutFragment.kt**

```
   private fun createConfirmOrderDialog() {
       val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
       builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.confirm_order))
           .setMessage(dialogPrompt)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm) { dialog, _ ->
               viewModel.placeOrder()
               dialog.dismiss()
           }
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { dialog, _ ->
               dialog.dismiss()
           }
       builder.show()
  }
```

**colors.xml**

`<color name="colorAccent">#F1CB1A</color> // I have this added to the base theme`

This setup, however, shows a dialog where the button text is not visible since both text and background is white.

[image: The resulting dialog]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you're calling the wrong overload of `setPositiveButton`. Try it with `.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm))`. Likewise for the negative case.

Comment: Not really, the button and text are present, and if I change the theme to Appcompat I can see them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the **`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`** instead of `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMessage(dialogPrompt)
        .setPositiveButton("OK",listener)
        .show()
```

The default color of the buttons is based on the `colorPrimary` color.

If you want to use a custom color you can use:

```
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context,R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
```

with this style

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/.....</item>
</style>

<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/....</item>
</style>
```